# Does Crusader Kings 2 Without DLCs Have factions?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I can't seem to find the factions tab where either I can join as a member or create one. I can't seem to find it beside nor in the Intrigue section. So I'm thinking if it exists in the original version without the DLC. OR is it because I created a new game and I did not have the tech I need for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this feature was introduced in the [free content patch](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Patch_1.07) that coincided with the release of the [paid DLC "Legacy of Rome"](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Legacy_of_Rome), if your game is up to date you should have this feature.